# what should be the time complexity for the following function?

Tags: c++, c, time, complexity-theory

Is time complexity of these two function same ??

```
void fun1()
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {    
        if(i%2==0)c++;
        if(i%3==0)c++;
    }
}
```

other function is -

```
void fun2()
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {    
        if(i%2==0)c++;

    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {    
        if(i%3==0)c++;
    }
}
```

I guess the time complexity for fun1 is O(n) and for fun2 is O(2n) Am I right ??

Comment: Yes you are right, but asking for such here isn't well appreciated. It's unlikely that this question is helpful for future research.

Comment: O(2n) is the same set as O(n), so both are O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You're correct about the first one. It will take n operations- O(n). For the second one, it will take 2 * n operations. In big O notations, the coefficients are ignored, leaving us with O(n) once again.

Answer (score -3):

just test and you will see that the first function is a bit faster than the second function. But the speed variate some times. This is cause the computer need to build again "int=0" and rise it to "n" and make "n" checks.
This code is slower :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n=10;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)cout<<"i%2"<<endl;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i%3==0)cout<<"i%3"<<endl;
    }

}
```

And this is faster:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n=10;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)cout<<"i%2"<<endl;
        if(i%3==0)cout<<"i%3"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The time complexity is the same though. That's not a matter of measuring but mathematical calculations.

Comment: **−1** "Faster" and "slower" area meaningless in this case without stating the compiler, version, full build command, details of the system it's run on.